# Access 2007 VBA - System.Text.Encoding.ASCII

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

Using Access 2007 VBA, I am trying to create an instance of the ASCII object (similar to usage in VB.NET) so I can convert string to byte array and vice-versa. I tried this by doing:

```
Dim ASCII As Object
Set ASCII = CreateObject("System.Text.Encoding.ASCII")
```

But, Access gives me an error saying:

> Run-time error '429':
>
> ActiveX component can't create object

Not sure why this is. Is this a no-no in VBA (versus VB.net)?  Can someone explain how I could do this, or if I can't WHY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct `ProgId` is `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding` :

```
Dim encoding As Object
Set encoding = CreateObject("System.Text.ASCIIEncoding")

Dim bytes() As Byte
bytes = encoding.GetBytes_4("abcde")
```

You could also get the ASCII bytes with `StrConv`:

```
Dim bytes() As Byte
bytes = VBA.StrConv("abcde", vbFromUnicode)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This does the trick.  Sorry for the delay... I've been quite sick.

Comment: Is there some kind of reference for these `ProgID's`?

Comment: The library is `mscorlib`, but the methods are not exposed for the `ASCIIEncoding` class.